# Django username already taken error

Tags: django

I have an form that allows a user to create a user account.The problem is , whenever a user submit a username that already been taken through the system . The form doesn't raise an error but it does raise an error when a field is missing. Can someone kindly help me

```
def Registration(request):  
    form = UserRegistration()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = UserRegistration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'], 
                email=form.cleaned_data['email'], 
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                )
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
             return render(request,'choose.html',{'form':form})

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form},)
```

My forms.py

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field'})

    password = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
    )

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(UserRegistration, self).clean()
            username = cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = cleaned_data.get("password")

            user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
            if user :
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                        "That user is already taken , please select another ")


            return cleaned_data
```

My template

```
<form method ="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}


<span id="error">{{form.username.errors}}</span>
<span id="error2">{{form.email.errors}}</span>
<span id="error3">{{form.password.errors}}</span>

{{form.username}}
{{form.email}}
{{form.password}}
    <input type = "submit" value= "save" id="box2"/>
</form>
```

Comment: try the same with `clean_username` It should work

Comment: @karthikr I tried clean_username . It still won't raise any error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `exists`[0] method:

```
user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
if user.exists():
    raise forms.ValidationError("That user is already taken")
```

Edit:

Try using the `clean_username` method:

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    ....

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("That user is already taken")
        return username
```

You could add a Test to make sure it works:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class TestUniqueUsername(TestCase):

    def test_unique_username(self):
        User.objects.create(username='test', password='test', email='test@django.com')
        form = UserCreationForm(data={'username': 'test'})
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

[0] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Comment: You need to use this answer, and remove your custom clean method.

Comment: @santiagobasulto - you should add `return username` at the end of the `clean_username` method.

Comment: Yes @BurhanKhalid you're right. Thanks! It was really late here (i'm in Argentina) and didn't notice it. :)

Comment: +1 from me as well.  For people arriving via google:  You can also use this technique with other fields. For ex you need unique email addresses:

        def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("That email is already in use.")
        return email

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
class UserRegistration(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required':'Error Missing Field , Please Fill this Field'})

    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
    )

    def clean_username(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        username = cleaned_data.get("username")
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if user.count() > 0:
            raise forms.ValidationError("That user is already taken , please select another ")
        return username
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Please recheck your code. This will surely work. I used this code in many of my projects and its working fine in all those projects.

Comment: You don't need `> 0`, simply `if user.count()`